# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null when using Typedjs

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typedjs

I would use TypedJS library.

I have installed it using `npm install typed.js`
Then included typed.js file in .angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed.js"
],
```

in my component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Typed from 'typed.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a-propos',
  templateUrl: './a-propos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a-propos.component.css']
})
export class AProposComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var typed2 = new Typed('#typed', {
      strings: ["<b>#Font End ?</b>", "<b>#Front End ?</b>", "<b>#Back End ?</b>", "<b> #Fullstack ?</b>", "<b>ça m'interesse !</b>"],
      typeSpeed: 30,
      backDelay: 2000,
      loop: true,

    });
  }
}
```

And HTML

```
<p id="typed"> </p>
```

I get this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
```

Comment: The typed library is expecting the selector to be tagname instead of id i believe.

Comment: Tried to add 'tagName' to html but not working

Comment: you do not need to add tagName to HTML its already the tagName. In your case the tagName would be 'p'

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Typed object after your view has initialized.

```
export class AProposComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var typed2 = new Typed('#typed', {
      strings: ["<b>#Font End ?</b>", "<b>#Front End ?</b>", "<b>#Back End ?</b>", "<b> #Fullstack ?</b>", "<b>ça m'interesse !</b>"],
      typeSpeed: 30,
      backDelay: 2000,
      loop: true,

    });
  }
}
```